# Site error when using www. in the URL

Tags: error, htaccess

I'm completely running stuck at the moment. In first place I had an issue that if I typed `www.mydomain.nl`, the user always was redirected to `mydomain.nl`. No idea why and I wanted to force the user to access the site with `www.` in the URL. So started looking at this an somehow (without changing a thing I believe), I can now access the site with `www.` in the URL, so not being redirected anymore.

However, I'm now getting a Site Error if I access the site when using the URL with `www.` in front of it. But the site is working fine without the prefix. I don't understand it anymore.

Working: `http://domain.nl`

Not working: `http://www.domain.nl`.

Giving this error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found
```

.htaccess file which is unchanged:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If I search for this error, I mostly reed about database errors. But how would a `www` in the URL break up a database connection.

database.php file in system/expressionengine/config/

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = 'expressionengine';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['expressionengine']['username'] = 'someUser';
$db['expressionengine']['password'] = 'thePassword';
$db['expressionengine']['database'] = 'someDatabase';
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
$db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = 'system/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';

/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./system/expressionengine/config/database.php */
```

Comment: Are you using Master Config? If so, you'll need to add the www domain separately to your environment file.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel, No, I'm not using that. Should I?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you edit your question to show your database.php config file? Please replace all the usernames and passwords with fake values.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel, updated my question with the database.php file!

Comment: Ok that's odd. I was expecting that you'd have some code that was changing the database based on the hostname. The error you're getting is because EE can't connect to the database.